# SQL Server 2008 - Windows form check box is checked if field in sql table is 'Y'?

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008, checkbox, visual-studio-2013

I would like to know if it is possible to open up a windows form application and have it compare against a specific table in SQL Server (field is "Report Active"), and if field value is 'Y', the check box comes pre-checked.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that's possible. Read the value from the database before the form is displayed, and then initialize the checkbox based on whether or not that field value is "Y". If you do the first parts (read the value from the database before the form is displayed), you can include that code here and then ask how to initialize the checkbox using that field's value. There are dozens (if not more) posts here about using databases from C# WinForms applications; search for them to get you started.

Comment: Thank you for such a quick reply.  You definitely pointed me in the right direction.  I will do some more research and post here with what I am able to come up with.